# Parse/Read a double at a known start position in a string

Tags: c#, parsing, double, cultureinfo

Is there something that can read a double from a known start position in a string?

I want to avoid the allocation in `double.Parse(s.Substring(...))`
Also the split is nontrivial with numberstyles & cultures.

It feels like there must be something in the framework but I cannot find it.

The signature would look like:

```
var d = double.Parse(text, startPos, numberstyles, formatProvider, out endPos);
```

Comment: No. There is no overload like that for `Parse`, but you can write your own extension method for that.

Comment: You could certainly write your own

Comment: *the split is nontrivial with numberstyles & cultures* - why is that? Do you means `Substring` as a *split* too?

Comment: I hesitate to write my own due to all edge cases: 
- abcNaNdef 
- abc1.2e3def
- abc+1,23def
@Sinatr 
Fun code to write but edge case fest.

Comment: Doing a maximal parse without a well-known end marker/delimeter in a string is likely to cause issues...

Comment: I've made custom parsing methods for this purpose, it's not too hard (if you have an invariant culture, of course). But do note that even using unsafe code, the speedup compared to a naive `Substring` solution was only about 2x - still the same magnitude. Is that kind of thing worth your time building and debugging parsing code?

Comment: @Luaan, the far end split is the same problem as parsing it. I'm asking the question because I feel there must be something in the framework that does it that I can't find.

Comment: Well, in that case your search is over - there actually isn't. .NET's string parsing isn't one of its strong points. If you wanted to do the same thing with binary values, that's easy - but there's no such overloads for strings. The split should be easy if you're using invariant culture; if you're not, why not? :D

Comment: Could you give an example of an input string? I mean, if there's just numbers in the string, how to determine where your double ends? There must be some sort of non-numeric character at the end. And then it's probably a RegEx thing plus double.Parse()

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wrote, yes it allocates:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

internal static class DoubleParser
{
    private const NumberStyles InvalidNumberStyles = ~(NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite |
                                                       NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite |
                                                       NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign |
                                                       NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign |
                                                       NumberStyles.AllowParentheses |
                                                       NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint |
                                                       NumberStyles.AllowThousands |
                                                       NumberStyles.AllowExponent |
                                                       NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol |
                                                       NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

    private const string LeadingSignNotAllowed = "Leading sign not allowed";
    private const string ExponentNotAllowed = "Exponent not allowed";
    private const string DecimalPointNotAllowed = "Decimal point not allowed";

    internal static double Parse(
        string text,
        int start,
        NumberStyles style,
        IFormatProvider provider,
        out int endPos)
    {
        if (!IsValidFloatingPointStyle(style))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid NumberStyles", nameof(style));
        }

        if (style.HasFlag(NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Hex not supported", nameof(style));
        }

        double result;
        if (TryParse(text, start, style, provider, out result, out endPos))
        {
            return result;
        }

        var message = $"Expected to find a double starting at index {start}\r\n" +
                      $"String: {text}\r\n" +
                      $"        {new string(' ', start)}^";
        throw new FormatException(message);
    }

    internal static bool TryParse(
        string text,
        int start,
        NumberStyles style,
        IFormatProvider provider,
        out double result,
        out int endPos)
    {
        result = 0;
        endPos = start;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!IsValidFloatingPointStyle(style))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (style.HasFlag(NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (style.HasFlag(NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite))
        {
            ReadWhite(text, ref endPos);
        }

        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(text[endPos]))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (TryParseDigits(text, endPos, style, provider, out result, out endPos))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (provider == null)
        {
            provider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        }

        var format = NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider);
        if (TryRead(text, ref endPos, format.NaNSymbol))
        {
            result = double.NaN;
            return true;
        }

        if (TryRead(text, ref endPos, format.PositiveInfinitySymbol))
        {
            result = double.PositiveInfinity;
            return true;
        }

        if (TryRead(text, ref endPos, format.NegativeInfinitySymbol))
        {
            result = double.NegativeInfinity;
            return true;
        }

        endPos = start;
        return false;
    }

    // Try parse a double from digits ignoring +-Inf and NaN
    private static bool TryParseDigits(
        string text,
        int start,
        NumberStyles style,
        IFormatProvider provider,
        out double result,
        out int end)
    {
        end = start;
        var format = NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider);
        Sign sign;
        if (TryReadSign(text, ref end, format, out sign))
        {
            if (!style.HasFlag(NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign))
            {
                result = 0;
                return false;
            }
        }

        TryReadDigits(text, ref end);

        if (TryRead(text, ref end, format.NumberDecimalSeparator))
        {
            if (!style.HasFlag(NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint))
            {
                result = 0;
                return false;
            }

            TryReadDigits(text, ref end);
        }

        if (TryReadExponent(text, ref end))
        {
            if (!style.HasFlag(NumberStyles.AllowExponent))
            {
                result = 0;
                return false;
            }

            TryReadSign(text, ref end, format, out sign);
            if (TryReadDigits(text, ref end))
            {
                return TryParseSubString(text, start, ref end, style, provider, out result);
            }

            // This is a tricky spot we read digits followed by (sign) exponent 
            // then no digits were thrown. I choose to return the double here.
            // Both alternatives will be wrong in some situations.
            // returning false here would make it impossible to parse 1.2eV
            var backStep = sign == Sign.None
                ? 1
                : 2;
            end -= backStep;
            return TryParseSubString(text, start, ref end, style, provider, out result);
        }

        return TryParseSubString(text, start, ref end, style, provider, out result);
    }

    private static bool TryParseSubString(
        string text,
        int start,
        ref int end,
        NumberStyles style,
        IFormatProvider provider,
        out double result)
    {
        var s = text.Substring(start, end - start);
        var success = double.TryParse(s, style, provider, out result);
        if (!success)
        {
            end = start;
        }
        return success;
    }

    private static bool TryReadSign(string s,
        ref int pos,
        NumberFormatInfo format,
        out Sign sign)
    {
        if (TryRead(s, ref pos, format.PositiveSign))
        {
            sign = Sign.Positive;
            return true;
        }

        if (TryRead(s, ref pos, format.NegativeSign))
        {
            sign = Sign.Negative;
            return true;
        }

        sign = Sign.None;
        return false;
    }

    private static bool TryReadExponent(
        string s,
        ref int pos)
    {
        if (TryRead(s, ref pos, "E"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (TryRead(s, ref pos, "e"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static bool TryReadDigits(string s, ref int pos)
    {
        var start = pos;
        while (pos < s.Length && char.IsDigit(s[pos]))
        {
            pos++;
        }

        return pos != start;
    }

    private static bool TryRead(string s, ref int pos, string toRead)
    {
        if (pos == s.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int start = pos;
        while (pos < s.Length &&
               pos - start < toRead.Length)
        {
            if (s[pos] != toRead[pos - start])
            {
                pos = start;
                return false;
            }
            pos++;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static void ReadWhite(string s, ref int pos)
    {
        while (pos < s.Length && Char.IsWhiteSpace(s[pos]))
        {
            pos++;
        }
    }

    private static bool IsValidFloatingPointStyle(NumberStyles style)
    {
        // Check for undefined flags
        return (style & InvalidNumberStyles) == 0;
    }
}
```

Sadly it allocates a substring. IIRC the next version of C# will have cheaper allocations for substrings, until then all the nasty optimized code is wasted :)
It handles the test cases i could think of.
It reads as long as it is a valid double. The problem is impossible to solve for the general case but it works for what I need it to.

Perhaps it is useful for someone.